How do I get user input's slot name in Lambda
I am working on AWS Lex V2 console. My Lambda is written in JavaScript. I can retrieve user input with following command:
let userInput = event.inputTranscript;

I want to know how do I get slot name of current user input?

You can access the slot name by filtering the event.sessionState.intent.slots (Source) object. Below is an example code:
export async function handler(event) {
 const userInput = event.inputTrascript;
 const slots = event?.sessionState?.intent?.slots || {};

 let currentSlotName;
 for (const [slotName, slot] of Object.entries(slots)) {
   if (slot.value.interpretedValue === userInput) {
     currentSlotName = slotName;
     break;
   }
 }

 console.log(currentSlotName);
}


Thanks @allan-chua I tried your code but could not iterate slots.

Can you at least log the value of your event object and share its structure here?
